# Custom endpoint with basic serializer?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

In my model's viewset, I have created a custom endpoint and I'm trying to serialize some quick meta information to send out.

Endpoint Declaration:

```
@list_route(methods=['get'], url_path='meta')
def get_meta_details(self, request):
    serializer = ThingMetaSerializer
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

ThingMetaSerializer:

```
class ThingMetaSerializer(serializers.Serializer):

    some_data = serializers.SerializerMethodField(method_name='ret_zero')

    def ret_zero(self):
        return 0
```

Every time I run the endpoint I get the following error:

> TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")

Any idea how I can make this work?

Edit:

I made this work using the following code in the viewset:

```
meta_data = {
    'some_data': 0,
}

@list_route(methods=['get'], url_path='meta')
def get_meta_details(self, request):
    # do some calculations
    return JsonResponse(self.meta_data)
```

However this method does not auto generate into the Django RF Schema. If there is a better way of doing this I would love to know.

Comment: You need to get an instance of Thing and pass it to the serializer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
serializer = ThingMetaSerializer
```

This doesn't initialize the *serializer*. You should use:

```
serializer = ThingMetaSerializer(instance={'some field': 'some data'})
```

instead.